# PostgreSQL cannot connect: service definition not found

Tags: windows, postgresql, symfony

In Windows 10 Pro 64-bit & new installation of PostgreSQL 9.4, attempting to connect to the server in pgAdmin III results in

[image: error screen]

The service is running and the service name is correct, as seen here

[image: windows service dialog]

I am brand new to PostgreSQL, but fwiw, I've configured a working Symfony 2.7 application to use PostgreSQL and have successfully (according to the Symfony console) created a database and its schema.

What is required to get pgAdmin to connect properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the error message is grossly misleading.  There is no issue with the service definition.  Instead, I learned that when logged in as a user other than the user that created the PostgreSQL installation (e.g., *postgres*) one needs to do this at the command prompt:

```
runas /user:postgres "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\pgAdmin3.exe"
```

There may be a more elegant solution than making the above a cmd file.  I'd like to know what that is!