# PostgreSQL definition of service not found (pgAdmin, psql, ...)

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin, libpq

## Context

I have a simple `pg_service.conf` file located at `${HOME}/pg_service.conf` which content is as follow:

```
# comment
[service_name]
host=localhost
port=5432
dbname=databasename
user=username
```

## Issue

Whenever I try to create a new server from [pgAdmin III](https://www.pgadmin.org/) by setting  'service_name' under the option 'Service', I  encounter this error message:

[image: pgAdmin III error box]

I also tried to copy the [`pg_service.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/libpq-pgservice.html) file nearby the [`.pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and restarting [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/); the same problem occurred.

A same error occurs when I try to run a [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-psql.html) command:

```
psql: definition of service "service_name" not found
```

How could I make it work?
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886549/postgresql-cannot-connect-service-definition-not-found), but that doesn't help me much because it's for Windows users.

## Environment

I'm on [Ubuntu 18.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.4/) using `"PostgreSQL 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. User based solution

Beware of the dot `.` in front of the file name!
The following setup works with PG 10.12 on CentOS 7.7 and `.pg_service.conf` located in `$HOME` directory:

```
   $ cat .pg_service.conf 
    [service_name]
    host=localhost
    port=5410
    dbname=postgres
    user=postgres
```

Then connect to PostgreSQL as follow;

```
    $ psql postgresql://?service=service_name
    psql (10.12)
    Type "help" for help.
```

Port checking:

```
    postgres=# show port;
     port 
    ------
     5410
    (1 row)
```

Connection checking:

```
    postgres=# \c
    You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres".
    postgres=#
```

## 2. System-wide solution

You can type this to check for the path where the global `pg_service.conf` file has to be located:

```
$ pg_config --sysconfdir
/etc/postgresql-common
```

You can copy your `pg_service.conf` file in this directory (but without the dot `.` here). It has to be own by root.

## General hints

### 1) File precedence

As stated in the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-methods.html);

> "The user file takes precedence over of the  system-wide file."

### 2) Password

In the case of a [peer authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-methods.html), both solutions should work with a password stored in your `.pgpass` file. In that case, you don't need to write it in the `.pg_service.conf` file.

Comment: Are you sure the psql command and its output is part of the file? It looks strange to me...

Comment: I've fixed the code output: the psql command and its output are not part of .pg_service.conf.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue when changing to `user=postgres` in the service file. Launching `psql postgresql://?service=service_name` raise the same error; `psql: definition of service "service_name" not found.`

Comment: Did you make sure that the service file is located in $HOME and named`.pg_service.conf` (with the initial dot) ? In my setup this work whether I'm connected with Linux 'postgres' user or with 'pierre' user.

Comment: You are perfectly right, I missed it! It's working now. Notice the file has to be prefixed with a dot `.` inside your home directory, but no dot is required if it's a system-wide file.

Comment: Same error here. I have already tried creating ~/.pg_service.conf file with the connection string, set the service name between brackets and still get the very same error. BTW both guest and host are Linux in my case:  

Unable to connect to server: connection is bad: definition of service "<what_to_place_here?>" not found.

pgAdmin version 8.3

Comment: Do you need to do something else after creating such .pg_service.conf file like restarting some service or so?